# Why custom cell in 'Grouped' style always show default height? I won't use 'heightForRow'

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

I'd like to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to get the cell height.

The confused problem is, in `Plain` style the custom cell returns custom height, I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` well.
But in `Grouped` style the cell height always returns default 44, and I change the style back to `Plain`, oh no, both badly return 44. You can try it.

And I reset the cell custom, the `Plain` style cells come to life.

I think there is a bug in `Grouped` style (InterfaceBuilding whatever...), how to solve the problem?

I just want to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in `Grouped` style.
By the way, bug shows in ipad and simulator, iphone shows well.